# How to update table column in SQL Server only wherever null appears?

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

I have a SQL Server table with more than 15 columns.

One of my column name is `verification_Status`. Currently, I have `0, 1, 2, null` values under `verification_Status` as below:

For example:

```
Id     Name      verification_Status
1       John       0
2       Kat        1
3       Williams   Null
4       Rosy       null
```

I want to make 0 wherever null appears. I have 4k rows to update so I am little worried.

```
update masterTable 
set verification_Status = 0 
where verification_Status == null
```

I am planning to use above query.

May I know this is the right query to my problem? Can someone guide me on this?

Comment: you are almost there..just use `where verification_Status is null`

Comment: 4K records, even with 15 columns shouldn't see a performance hit if it is a one time or scheduled job. Now if you were doing this every second then I would consider setting the default column attribute to 0 so it is always a 0 on insert if NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
update masterTable 
set verification_Status = 0 
where verification_Status is null
```

`<>` is Standard SQL; `!=` is its T-SQL equivalent. Both evaluate for values, which `NULL` is not -- NULL is a placeholder to say there is the absence of a value.

Which is why you can only use `IS NULL` / `IS NOT NULL` as predicates for such situations.

This is standard of all kinds of SQL management platforms

refer this: [Null (SQL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL))

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole, if it meets your requirement you can consider it to accept as your Answer

Comment: yes but it says wait 6 minutes to make answer as marked

Answer (score 3):

Your query should be

```
update masterTable set verification_Status=0 where verification_Status is null
```

Because `NUll=NUll` always`False`. So the records which will have value as NULL in verification_status will not update zero. so you should use `Verification_status is null` at where clause.

Answer (score 1):

Periodic update of value:

```
update masterTable set verification_Status=0 where verification_Status is null
```

Permanent Default Value on any table insert:

```
ALTER TABLE {TABLENAME} 
ADD {COLUMNNAME} {TYPE} {NULL|NOT NULL} 
CONSTRAINT {CONSTRAINT_NAME} DEFAULT {DEFAULT_VALUE}
[WITH VALUES]
```

Answer (score 1):

Check number of rows will affect before updating.

```
Select Count(*) from masterTable WHERE ISNULL(verification_Status,'') = ''
```

It is possible you also have empty string instead of null value in some columns.

If you want to update empty values and null values then use this.

```
UPDATE masterTable SET verification_Status=0 WHERE ISNULL(verification_Status,'') = ''
```

Comment: It includes other values also which are '' (*blank*) and **NOT NULL**! And OP says, *I want to make 0 wherever null appears.*

Comment: Made changes in answer